# jQuery Newbie, is there a cleaner way to write this code?

Tags: jquery, refactoring

Hoping someone can help me, this jQuery code Works, but i was wondering if there is a better way to structure it, looks like it could be refactored to be cleaner and easier to read. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery(".mobile-search").hide();
            jQuery(".search_show").show();
            jQuery(".mobile-top-links").hide();
            jQuery(".account_show").show();
            jQuery(".mobile-checkout").hide();
            jQuery(".cart_show").show();

            jQuery('.search_show').click(function(){
                jQuery(".mobile-search").slideToggle();
            });
            jQuery('.account_show').click(function(){
                jQuery(".mobile-top-links").slideToggle();
            });
            jQuery('.cart_show').click(function(){
                jQuery(".mobile-checkout").slideToggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: show HTML code so we can give you other selector options.

Comment: replace `jQuery` with `$` is a good start

Comment: @Nilzone- he could be using `noConflict()`

Comment: I'm sure you can turn those three click handlers into a single one with the use of `data-*` attributes and a shared class. If you can post your HTML I can write some code to show you how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have quite many options to make your code cleaner. This is what I would do.
I would add some additional classes to the elements:

```
<div class="mobile-search hidden">Search!</div>
<div class="search_show clickable" rel="mobile-search">Toggle Search</div>
```

And here's the Javascript.

```
jQuery('document').ready(function()
{
    jQuery('.clickable').click(function()
    {
        var selector_class = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
        jQuery('.' + selector_class).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

And some CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

You can have a look at this jsFiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yrBxH/

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
    .mobile-search, .mobile-top-links, .mobile-checkout: { display: none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".search_show").click(function(){
            jQuery(".mobile-search").slideToggle();
        });
        jQuery(".account_show").click(function(){
            jQuery(".mobile-top-links").slideToggle();
        });
        jQuery(".cart_show").click(function(){
            jQuery(".mobile-checkout").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css to hide and show since its on document ready you dont need to use jQuery to hide it

```
.mobile-search, .mobile-top-links, .mobile-checkout {
    display: none;
}
.cart_show, .account_show, .search_show {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use '$' instead of jquery if you are not using $ as any other symbol.
 example:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".mobile-search,.mobile-top-links,.mobile-checkout").hide();
        $(".search_show,.account_show,.cart_show").show();

        $('.search_show').click(function(){
            $(".mobile-search").slideToggle();
        });
        $('.account_show').click(function(){
            $(".mobile-top-links").slideToggle();
        });
        $('.cart_show').click(function(){
            $(".mobile-checkout").slideToggle();
        });
    });
```

I have combined few queries for common type operations.

Answer (score 0):

The hide/show calls can be written as:

```
jQuery(".mobile-search, .mobile-top-links, .mobile-checkout").hide();
jQuery(".search_show, .account_show, .cart_show").show();
```

The .click() calls should be fine already.

Answer (score 0):

first you can write the show and hide like this:

```
$(".mobile-search, .mobile-top-links, .mobile-checkout").hide();
$(".search_show, .account_show, .cart_show").show();
```

second, you can use `$` instead of `jQuery` if you're not already using `noConflict()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$` instead of `jQuery`, but if `$` conflict with other libraries, use a `(function($){ ...})(jQuery)` to wrap it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".mobile-search, .mobile-top-links, .mobile-checkout").hide();
        $(".search_show, .account_show, .cart_show").show();

        $('.search_show').click(function(){
            $(".mobile-search").slideToggle();
        });
        $('.account_show').click(function(){
            $(".mobile-top-links").slideToggle();
        });
        $('.cart_show').click(function(){
            $(".mobile-checkout").slideToggle();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```